# C# Checking if a service is set to Automatic (Delayed Start)

Tags: c#, service

I am trying to gather data on services being run on various servers in my domain.  For each server to check, I am getting a list of services

```
ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices(server);
```

From there, I am checking each ServiceController object in services for its ServiceStartMode and ServiceControllerStatus

```
if (sc.StartType == ServiceStartMode.Automatic && sc.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
```

The issue I am having is with services that are Automatic (Delayed Start) - I want to exclude those from the conditional statement above, but Delayed Start does not seem to be a member of the ServiceStartMode enum.

What are some ways I can find out if a service is Delayed Start so those services can be excluded from my search?

Comment: I think you may have to query the registry...

Comment: Or use WMI + Win32_Service which has a delayed start flag.

Comment: Good call @AlexK., that's going to be a lot faster (and safer)

Comment: @AlexK. Yes, the flag is there, but only for Server 2016 / Windows 10 and newer.  How can I monitor these services on 2012 / 2008 servers still in my domain?

Answer (score 2):

Windows keeps its service data in the registry under \\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services.

You can query the service's **Start** and the **DelayedAutostart** values to check this. If you set the service to Automatic (Delayed Start) manually then the DelayedAutostart value will be created only after reboot.

```
private static bool GetDelayedStatus(string serviceName, string machineName)
{
    using (var regKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, machineName))
    {
        using (RegistryKey serviceKey = regKey.OpenSubKey(@"System\CurrentControlSet\Services\" + serviceName, false))
        {
            int startMode = (int)serviceKey.GetValue("Start", 0, RegistryValueOptions.None);
            int delayedAutostart = (int)serviceKey.GetValue("DelayedAutostart", 0, RegistryValueOptions.None);

            return startMode == 2 && delayedAutostart == 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted sets `OpenSubKey( ..., writable: true)` which is unnecessary and may cause security exceptions (e.g. require UAC elevation) - provided one is just reading the registry you can use `writable: false` and it should work without elevation.

Comment: Good point, I edited my answer